# How do I reduce high CPU usage because of a C# Windows forms custom control being redrawn frequently?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

[Ogmo Editor](https://bitbucket.org/MattThorson/ogmoeditor/src) is a nice open source 2D map editor written in C# which unfortunately has a high CPU usage problem - whenever you open the actual level editing screen it completely saturates a single CPU core. I looked into the [source](https://bitbucket.org/MattThorson/ogmoeditor/src) and after profiling it came to the conclusion that the [OnPaint handler](https://bitbucket.org/MattThorson/ogmoeditor/src/9886b465f5a90f5d69b17c43cc5091459cd6e117/OgmoEditor/LevelEditors/LevelEditor.cs?at=default#cl-95) of the [LevelEditor custom control](https://bitbucket.org/MattThorson/ogmoeditor/src/9886b465f5a90f5d69b17c43cc5091459cd6e117/OgmoEditor/LevelEditors/LevelEditor.cs?at=default) is being called repeatedly. I am not very familiar with the Windows Forms API and checked the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about custom controls but was unable to determine the source of the problem.

I then looked into another similar open source project called [tIDE](http://tide.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) which to me seems to be rendering its editing screen - the [MapPanel control](http://tide.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TileMapEditor/tIDE/Controls/MapPanel.cs) in a very similar manner - please see the OnMapPaint() function definition in the link for details.

I am not sure why the control should refresh when it is not changing, I think someone familiar with the API may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: Why not contact the creator and report this issue?

Comment: This issue has been [reported](https://bitbucket.org/MattThorson/ogmoeditor/issue/26/ogmo-editor-uses-50-cpu) although without the code details - if you check the project history there has not been activity in the past 8 months and development might have been halted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following code in the [level editor file](https://bitbucket.org/MattThorson/ogmoeditor/src/9886b465f5a90f5d69b17c43cc5091459cd6e117/OgmoEditor/LevelEditors/LevelEditor.cs?at=default):

```
 void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Invalidate();
      LevelView.Update();
 }
```

The [Application Idle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event occurs just before the application is about to become idle and this resulted in an infinite redraw loop which is very processor intensive. Removing the Invalidate() call required updating the code to redraw whenever a user interaction occurs, this required changes to multiple files in the project and the resulting commit can be seen [here on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/vishalh/ogmoeditor/commits/8e14371f7c453531cfe2af36693a22b5b4386938).

For anyone else having similar issues the problem of excessive redraws is likely to be caused because of changes to the control or manual Invalidate() calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Derive your own `CustomLevelEditor` from `OgmoEditor.LevelEditors.LevelEditor`. Then override the OnPaint event like this.

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```

Sleeping for 1ms in the UI thread between paint events will bring the CPU cycles down significantly. If `OnPaint` gets fired by the base control non-stop, then you might try something like this.

```
    int paintReps = 0;

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

        if(paintReps++ % 500 == 0)
            Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

Comment: I was playing around with your solution and cut CPU usage of a single core to 50%, but with a 20ms sleep delay for which the UI was usable (the other part to run blocked events did not help), but this did not address my problem completely. Your answer, however, did prompt me to go over the code again after almost giving up on finding the solution and I discovered an unnecessary Invalidate() call which was causing the problem so thank you for the input. This answer can help other users having similar problems.

Comment: No problem Vishal! I find that mostly people solve their own problems. Other people simply help to remind of a different perspective. Ruling things out is just as good as ruling things in. If Invalidate() was being called in a loop then you probably don't even need the derived class. Perfect solution. Congrats!